# Working with Map Series in Map View to assist Editing in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, editing, map-series

In ArcMap I sometimes used Data Driven Pages to actually compare features and make edits.  For example, I have two feature classes consisting of the same list of addresses geocoded via different locator services.  If feature class A is more accurate over all but feature class B has a few points that are more accurate, I'd want to move those points in A to match those of B.  I could do this easily in ArcMap; just turn on Data Driven Pages and click the arrow on the toolbar to cycle through all the features and do my manual inspection of the two features.

In ArcGIS Pro it seems like the replacement for Data Driven Pages, the Map Series, is only available in Layout View.  If I want to do the same thing in ArcGIS Pro, I have to go to Layout View, add the map series, click the first index, go back over to map view to perform any edits I may need to make, click back over to Layout view, click the next index in the series, repeat.  Lots of extra clicking for the same functionality.

Is there a way to enable Map Series in Map View?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of "a way to enable Map Series in Map View".

However, I think a workflow that approximates to yours is to open the attribute table of the layer you have been using as your Data Driven Pages index and then using the grey left-hand cell to zoom to each feature in turn.